# passoword validation without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a password validation using js and html. It suppose to show certain information under the input parts if the input is not valid. But whatever the input is, there's no message at all. I am not sure which part I did wrong. Code is posted below

```js
        var name = document.getElementById("userName");
        var passWord = document.getElementById("passWord");
        var flag;
        
        function check() {
            flag = validateInput(name, passWord);
            if (flag) 
                isPaswordValid(passWord);
            if (flag) 
                ispassWordStrong(passWord);
        }
        
        function validateInput(name, passWord) {
            if (name.length = 0 || passWord.length < 0) {
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please enter Username and passWord";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Valid input";
                return true;
            }
        }

            //Check Username and passWord are valid
            function isPaswordValid(passWord) {
                var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;

                //Check passWord is valid or not and having length of passord should not less than 8
                if (passWord.length < 8 || (!re.test(passWord))) {
                    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Invalid passWord. Please enter new passWord";
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Valid input";
                return true;
                }               
            }

            //Check password has no more than 3 characters from username in passWord
            function ispassWordStrong(userName, passWord) {
                var n = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < userName.length; i++) {
                    if (passWord.indexOf(userName[i]) >= 0) {
                        n += 1;
                    }
                }

                if (n > 3) {
                    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "passWord can't contain more than 3 characters from the username.";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Valid input";
                }               
            }
        });
```

```html
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Password Validator</legend>
        User Name:
        <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" onkeyup='check();' /><br>
        passWord:
        <input type="password" id="passWord" name="passWord" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='check();' />
        <input type="submit" id="inputValidate" value="Validate"><br /><br />
        <b><span style="color:red;" id="errorMessage"></span></b>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

Sorry for the long codes and thanks for your help.

Comment: *"not working"* doesn't tell us anything very meaningful about what does or doesn't happen, or any errors thrown in browser dev tools console or steps you have taken to debug this

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for commenting. edited the question

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_password_val

Comment: Check your ``check();`` function - that if-statement is very incorrect. Also, learn how to check the console; there are errors you might need to address.

Comment: just to start: `if (name.length = 0 || passWord.length < 0) {` should be `if (name.length == 0 || passWord.length < 8) {` First you have to compare (==) values not assign (=). Also an input will never be <0. You probably meant to check if the input has a minimum value. Otherwise instead of `<8` put `==0` again

Comment: Your code `var name = document.getElementById("userName");` gets the DOM element, and not just its text value. Use `var name = document.getElementById("userName").value;` to get the text value. Same for `passWord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you require:

```js
// collect all DOM elements in object ti: ti.i, ti.e, ti.u, ti.p
const ti=["inputValidate","errorMessage","userName","passWord"]
  .reduce((a,c)=>(a[c.substr(0,1)]=document.querySelector('#'+c),a),{});

// delegated event listening for event "input":
document.querySelector('fieldset').addEventListener('input',ev=>{
  if (Object.values(ti).indexOf(ev.target)>1){ // for userName and passWord do ...
    let u=ti.u.value.toLowerCase();
    ti.e.textContent= (ti.p.value.length > 2
              && ti.p.value.split('').reduce((a,c)=>a+=u.indexOf(c.toLowerCase())>-1?1:0,0) > 2 )
        ? "The password contains at least 3 letters from the username!" : "";
}})

// event listening for button click on "validate":
ti.i.addEventListener('click',ev=>!(ti.e.textContent=
  (ti.u.value.trim().length ? "" : "User name is empty.") ||
  (ti.p.value.match(/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/)
        ? "" : "The password is not complex enough!" )))
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Password Validator</legend>
  User Name:<br/>
  <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="User Name"/><br>
  passWord:<br/>
  <input type="password" id="passWord" name="passWord" placeholder="Password"/> 
  <input type="submit" id="inputValidate" value="Validate"><br/>
  <b><span style="color:red;" id="errorMessage"></span></b>
</fieldset>
```

While inputting characters in the fields `#userName` and `#passWord` it checks for the occurence of user name characters in the password. This is done ignoring upper or lower case. And when clicking on the "validate" button the complexity of the password is checked against the regular expression `/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/`. This regular expression demands at least

- one upper case chraracter,
- one lower case character
- one number and
- a minimum length of 8.

There is also a rudimentary check on the user name. It must contain at least one non-blank character. The event handler for the click event on the "validate" button returns `false` whenever an error is detected. This can be used to prevent the submission of the form. However, the form itself was not supplied by OP.